# Создаю базу данных в андроид приложении, но он полностью игнорирует первую таблицу и выдает ошибку когда я к ней обращаюсь

Tags: android, sqlite

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // конструктор суперкласса
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // создаем таблицу с полями
        db.execSQL("create table 'week' ("
                + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "begin_hours text,"
                + "end_hours text,"
                + "day_of_week integer,"
                + "number integer,"
                + "name text" + ");");

        db.execSQL("create table 'homeworks' ("
                + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "number integer,"
                + "day integer,"
                + "month integer,"
                + "year integer,"
                + "homework text" + ");");


        //Устанавливаем пустые строки в бд недели
        for(int dayOfWeek = 1; dayOfWeek <= 7; dayOfWeek++){
            for(int number = 1; number <= 7; number++){
               createWeek(dayOfWeek, number);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void test(){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          Cursor c = db.query("week", null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

}
```

Comment: сейчас заметил что в некоторых м естах он вдит таблицу week  a в некоторых нет

Comment: в андроид колонка ID должна обязательно иметь имя _id (не _ID), если вы хотите использовать стандартные классы андроид для работы с sqlite и хотите, чтобы они работали (так же эта колонка должна быть обязательно включена в выборку). Если вы вносите изменения в структуру БД (имена, количество таблиц и тп), то в период тестов перед изменением нужно обязательно деинсталировать приложение на тестирующем устройстве, иначе изменения не будут применены. Для   приложений у пользователей используется метод onUpgrade()

Comment: Простите. а почему тег вопроса - MySQL, хотя коннектор SQLite?

Comment: Извиняюсь, действительно перепутал тег

Comment: сменил _ID на _id - не помогло, например если запустить метод test, то все падает

Comment: даже положить данные получается а взять - нет

Comment: мой комментарий не должен был решить вашу проблему - это просто замечание о проблеме, с которой вы бы столкнулись позже. Например, в вашем вопросе нет никакого метода test(), кто то должен догадаться, что он делает и почему падает? Если приложение падает - в вопрос нужно добавить стектрейс при падении. Как и что у вас не получается взять опять же? Посмотрите на свой вопрос глазами человека, который видит только ваш вопрос и вспомните, что пишите вы не на передачу "битва экстрасенсов" ....

Answer (score 0):

Убери `' '` в названии таблиц. Ты в запросе пишешь без `' '`.